# how can i get the Hour only from textClock

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

> in this i am trying to get only hour from the textclock and show on my widget and it works perfectly on Android device and when test on BlackBerry it shows complete time like 12:50 PM instead of hour

```
              <TextClock
                android:id="@+id/tvHourWidget"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:format12Hour="hh"
                android:text="00"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/basic_twice" />
```

> here is the code i have tried

Comment: Where's the java code?

Comment: no java code i have used for that and i think there is no need of java code for the text clock

Comment: So it's just the `android:format12Hour="hh"` attribute that causes different behaviour on different devices?

Comment: There may be cases where the clock is 24 hours. Try adding the `android:format24Hour="hh"` attribute.

Comment: yes its causing the different behavior on devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set whether a device is 12-hour or 24-hour format, nor can you set that in your `TextView`. Hence, you'll have to use both `format12Hour` and `format24Hour` attributes to ensure that in both cases, the format will be `hh`:

```
<TextClock
            android:id="@+id/tvHourWidget"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:format12Hour="hh"
            android:format24Hour="hh"
            android:text="00"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/basic_twice" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a textview ,timer and a simpledateformater Instead and set the desired DATETIME format you wish

```
Timer tmm=new Timer();
public void start(TextView tv1){


    tmm.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tv1.setText(""+ my_time("HH"));
        }
    },1000,1000);

}
public void Stop()
{
    tmm.cancel();
}


        public static String my_time(String format)
        {
            try{
                return new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());


            }catch (Exception ex){}
            return null;
        }
```